# Problem with Multer 2.0.0-rc.1 ("path" argument must be of type string)

Tags: node.js, express, multer

While learning node / express, I try as best I can to use Multer... But I'm stuck!

(I'm using Multer version 2.0.0-rc.1)

I work with two main files (route and controller), this is how my user.route.js file is made up:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const uploadController = require("../controllers/upload.controller");
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();

...

router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), uploadController.uploadProfil);

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the content of my upload.controller.js file :

```
const UserModel = require("../models/user.model");
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { pipeline } = require("stream");
const { uploadErrors } = require("../utils/errors.utils");

module.exports.uploadProfil = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      req.file.detectedMimeType != "image/jpg" &&
      req.file.detectedMimeType != "image/png" &&
      req.file.detectedMimeType != "image/jpeg"
    )
      throw Error("invalid file");

    if (req.file.size > 500000) throw Error("max size");
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = uploadErrors(err);
    return res.status(201).json({ errors });
  }

  const fileName = req.body.name + ".jpg";
  const filePath = `./client/public/uploads/profil/${fileName}`;

  try {
    await pipeline(
      req.file.stream,
      fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
    );

    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.userId,
      { $set: { picture: "./uploads/profil/" + fileName } },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        else return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

And here is the error i get :

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
    at TempWriteStream.WriteStream (node:internal/fs/streams:328:5)
    at new TempWriteStream (C:...\node_modules\fs-temp\lib\write-stream.js:6:15)
    at Object.createWriteStream (C:...\node_modules\fs-temp\lib\temp.js:121:10)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:...\node_modules\multer\lib\read-body.js:70:27)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Busboy.emit (C:...\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:37:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:...\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:214:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:...\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:50:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:514:28) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

According to my research on different topics here and elsewhere, the problem comes from this part of the code:

```
const fileName = req.body.name + ".jpg";
  const filePath = `./client/public/uploads/profil/${fileName}`;

  try {
    await pipeline(
      req.file.stream,
      fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
    );
```

From what I understand, the path is not properly structured... but I don't understand why?

I looked for various solutions, but most of them use multer.diskStorage which no longer seems to be compatible with my version of Multer...

So I also tried to change the path with this code:

```
  await pipeline(
    req.file.stream,
    fs.createWriteStream(
      `${__dirname}/../client/public/uploads/profil/${fileName}`
    )
  );
```

and even use path.join.

But I get the same error... An idea ?
is this due to my Multer version?

Comment: you should change your multer configuration: `const storage = multer.memoryStorage();` and `const upload = multer({ storage: storage });` in your **user.route.js** file.